# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString([B)Ljava/lang/String

Tags: java, android, annotation-processor

I have included legacy.jar in my module

[image]

& added that module in app dependency also, added android annotation processor library (annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0')
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html

After running the project it is showing following error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':task'.
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString([B)Ljava/lang/String;

[image]
But after removing annotation processor library project runs successfully.

I am not sure why this error occurs.

below are my both Gradle files for myModule & app

**myModule Gradle file**

```
dependencies {        
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
}
```

**app Gradle file**

```
    dependencies {
    compile project(':myModule')
    compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0'
    compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
    compile 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha3'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
}
```